# Why hbase get function does't fetch the record?

Tags: java, hbase

I have a table with one column family and versioning disabled, as below. 
rowkey, E:T
The issue is, in few scenario's the get function is not returning the key which is already present in the table and hence inserting the same value again. 
could you please let me know if anyone has faced the similar issue.

Thanks.

Comment: To add few more details we have a RowKey value=KEY3TRxcfTldfgh (this is encrypted value of a long number) in the HBase the column family value for this RowKey gets overwritten even when we use the CheckandPut function with versioning =1

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [doc](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#checkAndPut-byte:A-byte:A-byte:A-byte:A-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put-), I understand that checkAndPut will check if the provided row/family/value matches the expected value and if yes, it will add the provided Put.

So in your case, I think the API is working as expected. If your intention is to add only if the record doesn't exist, then you can use exists method to know whether the record already exists. If not you can insert your record.

I hope this helps!